# Is there a map or list of all the lava tube skylights the LRO has detected on the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, planetary-science, mapping, lro

I have read that so far the LRO has detected about [200 skylights](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/display.cfm?News_ID=47903) - they appear to be holes into larger spaces below them, which could be lava tubes or domes.

[image: 10 skylights on the Moon]

I would really like to know where all of them are. ASU's [LRO site](http://lroc.sese.asu.edu/) has all the images and multiple ways to search through them, but I don't know how to search for this. There is the [RDR product search](http://wms.lroc.asu.edu/lroc/rdr_product_select#_ui-id-1) page... I don't know what that means but it looks like it might be the place if I knew how to use it.

But also, these are being actively searched for and there has to be a list out there of all of them, even a map. Does anyone know where?

Comment: This is for the purpose of siting a virtual Moon settlement - http://moonwards.com/ .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a map of lunar pits, created by R. V. Wagner and M. S. Robinson of the School of Earth and Space Exploration, Arizona State University, in 2014. From [Distribution, Age, and Formation Mechanisms of Lunar Pits](http://nesf2014.arc.nasa.gov/poster-uploader/files/Wagner_Robert_Lunar_Pits.pdf) (PDF) by mentioned authors:

> [image: Map of lunar pits]
>
> Map of the locations of all currently-known pits. Orange stars
>   indicate mare or highland pits, and blue dots indicate craters with
>   impact melt pits. 50° lines mark PitScan's search range.

Click on the image for a higher resolution version. Complete list with locations should be available in the [Distribution, formation mechanisms, and significance of lunar pits](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103514001857) Icarus volume by same authors, but is paywalled. From its highlights:

> - We developed an algorithm to search for collapse pits in LROC NAC images.
> - We found ten pits in maria and highlands, typically 40–100 m in diameter and depth.
> - We found over 200 pits in impact melt, which average 16 m in diameter and 7 m in depth.
> - Pits are often significantly younger than their host materials.
> - Some pits have confirmed overhangs, and may connect to larger sublunarean voids.

Authors have searched for lunar pits with own PitScan, a semi-automated search algorithm that scanned LROC NAC images for pit candidates, and 200x200 pixel crops were created for human confirmation. The algorithm went through a three-step process:

> 1. Determine a cut-off value for what is “shadowed” in the image.
> 2. Locate all blocks of "shadowed" pixels more than 10 pixels across.
> 3. For each such block of pixels, determine if the up-Sun or down-Sun side  of the shadow is brighter. If the up-Sun side is brighter, then
>      it is probably a rock, and should be ignored (see figure). Otherwise,
>      save a small image of the shadow for classification by a human.
>
>    [image: PitScan classification process]
>
>    Comparison of PitScan output for a pit (left) and a rock (right). Note the relative brightnesses of the up-Sun and down-Sun regions of the DN profiles (bottom panels).

---

About that *RDR*, it stands for *Reduced Data Record* and is described [in this LROC page](http://www.lroc.asu.edu/archive):

> LROC utilizes more than one million images we've colleted in a
>   variety of data products. An EDR (Engineering Data Record) is an image
>   and its associated metadata. A CDR is and EDR that has been
>   decompanded and calibrated. An RDR (Reduced Data Record) can be made
>   from as few as one image or as many as thousands that are processed
>   and reduced for the purpose of, for example, making a mosaic that
>   combines multiple images of a particular area or feature, or a high
>   resolution global digital elevation model created with stereo
>   observations.
>
> There are many way to search through LROC's Data products:
>
> - [Map Interface](http://wms.lroc.asu.edu/lroc)
> - [Browse EDRs and CDRs](http://wms.lroc.asu.edu/lroc/thumbnails)
> - [Search by metadata for EDRs and CDRs](http://wms.lroc.asu.edu/lroc/search)
> - [Search for RDRs](http://wms.lroc.asu.edu/lroc/rdr_product_select)

---

More info about lunar pits from Lunar and Planetary Science Conferences (this was bugging me because I couldn't remember where I saw talks on the topic):

- [Lunar Pits: Sublunarean Voids And The Nature Of Mare Emplacement](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2011/pdf/2771.pdf) (A. K. Boyd et al., 42nd LPSC 2012, PDF). Includes a LROC image table of some of them:

  > ```
  > Location             Image        Depth  Shadow  Diameter   Slew  Incidence  
  >                                     (m)  length  Max  Min  angle      angle  
  >                                             (m)  (m)  (m)    (°)        (°)
  > ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
  > Mare Tranquilitatis  M106662246R    102      60   97   86   0.00      30.52
  >                      M126710873R    106      53   95   85   0.00      26.56
  >                      M137332905R     92      70   98   81   7.05      37.37
  >                      M144395745L     NM      NM  100   NM -50.46      47.92        
  > ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
  > Marius Hills         M114328462R    >32*     NM   62   48   6.80      61.38
  >                      M122584310L     36      19   57   46   0.00      28.08
  >                      M133207316L     >8*     NM   76   61  29.13      82.84
  >                      M137929856R     NM      NM   NM   NM  42.86      33.79
  > ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
  > Mare Ingenii         M115225180L    >24      NM  146  107   0.00      74.52
  >                      M121124338L     68      87  125   97   0.00      52.00
  >                      M123485893R     47      38  104   68  -5.45      39.05
  >                      M128202846L     76     105  125   68   0.00      54.25
  >                      M136465172L    >47*     NM  110   73  15.51      55.47
  >                      M138819477R     52      42  101   73   0.00      38.91
  > ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
  > * depth estimate less certain due to high slew angles
  > NM not measureable
  > ```

  You can load images with [LROC Image Search](http://wms.lroc.asu.edu/lroc/search) if you copy the image name in the Product ID field, but sadly this source doesn't provide exact coordinates and images cover large areas and features discussed are tiny in comparison.
- [Electromagnetic Simulations of Ground-Penetrating Radar Propagation near Lunar Pits and Lava](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2013/pdf/1761.pdf) (M. I. Zimmerman et al., 44th LPSC 2014, PDF). Just an interesting read. Carry on. :)
- [A Reevaluation of Lunar Impact Pit Craters](http://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2014/pdf/2901.pdf) (P. T. Malinski et al., 45th LPSC 2015, PDF). Includes a map of surveyed pits using [Lunar Orbiter Laser Altimeter](http://lunar.gsfc.nasa.gov/lola/) (LOLA) data, which is another way to detect them, as we discussed in the chat:

  > [image: LOLA generated lunar surface with surveyed pits]
  >         LOLA generated lunar surface with surveyed pits (dots). The lines represent borders and the area between the lines represent the
  >   area survey for the lunar highlands.  Maria that fell within the
  >   highland study area were evaluated based upon their natural borders.

Comment: This really couldn't have been more exactly what i'd hoped for.